# MedianIf Function giving Run-timer Error '438'

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am failing to see the error in this line of code. Perhaps I need a second pair of eyes to recognize it:

```
targetWs.Cells(subRow, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.MedianIf(sourceWs.Range("X3:X92"), ">" & 0)
```

Comment: MedianIf is not a child of WorksheetFuntion.  It does not exist.

Comment: @ScottCraner Okay, thank you, what would I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MedianIf is not a child of WorksheetFuntion. It does not exist.

This would be the array formula:

```
MEDIAN(IF(X3:X92 > 0,X3:X92))
```

so we need to use Worksheet.Evaluate():

```
targetWs.Cells(subRow, 7) = sourceWs.Evaluate("MEDIAN(IF(X3:X92 > 0,X3:X92))")
```

Comment: ++ specially for `sourceWs.Evaluate` and not `Application.Evaluate`